# JavaScript Error: Invalid assignment left-hand side

Tags: javascript, loops, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-api

When I try to execute my code I get the error:

```
Invalid assignment left-hand side. (line 1, file "Code")
```

All my code is:

```
function sendEmails() {
    var emailAddress = "MyEmail@email.com";
    var message = "Message";   
    var subject = "Subject";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
         if (1 = 1) {
      sendEmails()
  }
  }
```

I am trying to loop this but it does not seem to work. I am a complete beginner. Thanks!

EDIT: it works if I just remove the:

```
     if (1 = 1) {
  sendEmails()
```

}

Comment: Answer is found easily on Google. Refrain from asking such questions

Comment: In javascript single = means you are assigning a value while in if it is expected to be a condition try something like this 1==1 or 1===1

Comment: Assuming you meant `==` or `===`, why are you testing if `1 == 1`? Might as well say `if(true)`, but if the condition is *always* true you don't need the `if` at all...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is that you are assigning within the `if` loop not comparing

Change to `1==1`

**For Future Reference**

1. This answer pops up on Google
2. Also test simple JavaScript code on
   a Browser's console `Chrome => Ctrl+Shift+I`

Comment: THANKS! Fixed it!

Comment: *"The error is that you are assigning within the if loop not comparing"* - (a) There is no loop. (b) Assignment within an `if` condition isn't a syntax error (it may be a program logic error).